# Python Selenium WebDriverWait on many loaded but nonclickable elements until one becomes clickable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm automating the click action on a <s>terribly</s> innovatively written website.
There are three button/clickable elements, all of them are loaded and have
`presence_of_element_located == True`
Only one will have `element_to_be_clickable == True`
I want to use `WebDriverWait` to wait on a single CSS selector `"a, b, c"`(so I can reuse the same code with other sites) until one of the buttons becomes clickable

DOM example of three buttons notes the one without `style="display: none;` might change:
`<button[class='AddCart1'] style="display: none;">`
`<button[class='AddCart2']>`
`<button[class='AddCart3']style="display: none;">`

My code:
`def wait_until_clickable(wd: webdriver, item_selector: str, timeout: int) -> None:`
    `WebDriverWait(wd, time_out).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, item_selector)))`

Resutls:

1. If the clickable element is the first in DOM, the `WebDriverWait until` returns the proper element
2. If the clickable element is not the first in DOM, TimeoutException is thrown

What I am expecting:

Regardless how `a, b , c` are ordered in DOM, the above code should always return the clickable element after the wait

From what I read, adding `,` in `CSS_SELECTOR` should act as an OR operator, but it doesn't seem to be the case here. Could someone help me to figure out how to do this properly?

The website is publicly accessible https://www.amiami.com/eng/. The button for pre-ordering and the button for adding in-stock items to cart are different (there exists a thrid `btn-cart` button but I have yet to figure out where it is used). Additionally, both buttons are always in DOM regardless of the status of the item (pre-order, available now, or out of stock), `style="display: none;` is used to control what content is displayed.

Comment: Can you share the url, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.